# OWL API: Traverse imported ontology

Tags: owl, ontology, owl-api, pellet

I'm trying to import an ontology to the primary ontology, and traverse over all classes:

```java
     manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
            ontology = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(new File("data/prim.owl"));
            factory = manager.getOWLDataFactory();
            OWLImportsDeclaration im = factory.getOWLImportsDeclaration(IRI.create("https://protege.stanford.edu/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl"));
            manager.applyChange(new AddImport(ontology,im));
            reasoner = OpenlletReasonerFactory.getInstance().createReasoner(ontology);
```

I’m running this code to get all classes:

```java
      //*********************
            Set<OWLClass> allCls = ontology.getClassesInSignature();
            allCls.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Classes belonging to `prim.owl` are returned, but classes in the imported ontology (`pizza.owl`) are not returned.

Comment: As usual, the [Javadoc](https://owlcs.github.io/owlapi/apidocs_5/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLSignatureBooleanArgs.html#getClassesInSignature-boolean-) is your friend ... as you can see if you click the link, there is the option to provide an argument: `Set<OWLClass> getClassesInSignature(boolean includeImportsClosure)` with the description *"includeImportsClosure - if true, include imports closure."*

Comment: Incidentally, to traverse all classes you don't need a reasoner.

Answer (score 1):

The code in the question contains a mistake: it does not load the desired imported ontology (pizza) into the manager.

```
OWLImportsDeclaration im = factory.getOWLImportsDeclaration(IRI.create("https://protege.stanford.edu/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl"));
manager.applyChange(new AddImport(ontology,im));
```

These lines just add the `owl:imports` declaration into the ontology header (`_:x a owl:Ontology`) for the pizza-iri.

To make the code work, you need to load the pizza-ontology separately:

```
OWLOntology pizza = manager.loadOntology(IRI.create("https://protege.stanford.edu/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl"));
OWLImportsDeclaration im = factory.getOWLImportsDeclaration(pizza.getOntologyID().getOntologyIRI().orElseThrow(AssertionError::new));
manager.applyChange(new AddImport(ontology, im));
```

Now you can check that all imports and references are really present and correct, and, therefore, your ontology has a reference to the pizza ontology:

```
Assert.assertEquals(1, ontology.importsDeclarations().count());
Assert.assertEquals(1, ontology.imports().count());
Assert.assertEquals(2, manager.ontologies().count());
```

Then you can get all OWL-classes from both ontologies as a single collection or java-Stream:

```
ontology.classesInSignature(Imports.INCLUDED).forEach(System.err::println);
```

Also please note: the method `Set<OWLClass> getClassesInSignature(boolean includeImportsClosure)` is deprecated (in OWL-API **v5**).

Comment: thanks, I'll try it out . is there any tutorial for OWL-API v5 library?